# VB.net Comparing multiple textboxes by checking if a number is greater than

Tags: vb.net

I have 18 textboxes that simply contains a number. 9 textboxes called `tbmax` (tbmax1-9) and 9 called `tbnumber` (tbnumber1-9). Like this: `tbnumber1`,    `tbnumber2`, `tbnumber3`... so on. And `tbmax1`, `tbmax2`, `tbmax3` and so on.

**This is what I want...**

If ANY of the numbers in `tbnumber(1-9).text` is greater than ANY of the numbers in `tbmax(1-9).text`, do something. In other words, if just one of the `tbnumber` textboxes has a larger number than just one of the `tbmax` texboxes, do something.

**Attempt 1**

```
For Count = 1 To 9
            Dim Tnumber = CType(Controls.Find("tbnumber" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
            Dim Tmax = CType(Controls.Find("tbmax" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
            If Tnumber.Text > Tmax.text Then
                'do something
next
end if
```

**Attempt 2**

```
Dim tbnumber_textboxes As New List(Of TextBox) From {tbNumber1,
     tbNumber2, tbNumber3, tbNumber4, tbNumber5, tbNumber6, tbNumber7,
     tbNumber8, tbNumber9}

Dim tbmax_textboxes As New List(Of TextBox) From {tbmax1, tbmax2, 
     tbmax3, tbmax4, tbmax5, tbmax6, tbmax7, tbmax8, tbmax9}

If tbNumber_textboxes.Any(Function(cb) cb.Text) > tbMax_textboxes.Any(Function(cb) cb.Text) Then
'Do something
'For example msgbox("A number is larger than any of the max-textboxes")
```

However, It doesn't seem to work and I'm not quite sure why. I think in my attempt 2 that "Any" is not the right usage for my purpose.

**Update for Thorsten's answer**

I've tested your method, and I removed the MaxVal to simplify my testing by putting a number in instead.

This is what I've got

```
For Count = 1 To 9
Dim Tnumber = CType(Controls.Find("tbnumber" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
Dim number = Convert.ToInt32(Tnumber.Text)
If (number > 0) And (number < 30) Then
tbTest1.Text = "0-30"
tbtest2.Text = number

elseif (number > 30) And (number < 50) Then
tbTest1.Text = "30-50"
tbtest2.Text = number
end if
next
```

This is how the tbnumber textboxes (1-9) are at the moment as I get `1`in `tbtest2.text`:

[image]

So what I notice is that `tbtest2.text` outputs `1` for some reason... `Number` should be the greatest number of any of the tbnumber1-9 textboxes.

Comment: Comment on *Update for Thorsten's answer*: No, by what your code says, `tbtest2.Text` will always be the text in `tbnumber9`. What's in there? A `1`?

Comment: Alright, I thought that was how it would work. `tbnumber9` at the moment has number `5`, and `tbtest2.text` still shows `1`

Comment: Are you sure that the control is actually being found? Did you check the exact spelling? Looking up controls by name is case sensitive, so it might be that you're not finding `tbnumber9`, thus the last value remains in `tbtest2`. You should get an NPE though...

Comment: Oh wow, I actually didn't know it was case sensitive. That solved it, so `tbtest2.text` now shows `5`. Great! However, I want `number` to show the greatest number of any of the tbnumber1-9 textboxes, not nessesarily `tbnumber9.text`. Is it small changes to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, it actually is a small change :-) Create another variable `maxNumber` and initially set it to `Int32.MinValue`. Whenever `number` is greater than `maxNumber`, set `maxNumber` to `number` and display `number` in `tbtest2`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get how its supposed to go, but _"Whenever number is greater than maxNumber, set maxNumber to number"_ this is where I get a bit confused. How would I set `maxNumber` to `number` if `number` is greater than `maxNumber`? Sorry for my confusion. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Declare `maxNumber` **outside the loop** and after the line where you get `number` from the text box, insert this line: `If (number > maxNumber) Then maxNumber = number End If`. Then, replace all occurrences of `tbtest2.Text = number` by `tbtest2.Text = maxNumber`. I'm going to edit my answer to show this better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had `maxNumber` inside the loop and used `number` instead of `maxnumber` for output. It's perfect now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1 looks promising to me (I'd have tried the same thing). However, you are not comparing the right values in the end.

```
If Tnumber.Text > Tmax Then 
            'do something
```

Your comparison above compares the **text** of the `Tnumber` textbox to the **instance** `Tmax` - you're comparing `String` with `TextBox`.

You need to get the text from both text boxes, convert them to `Int32` and then compare those two values. I'm not a VB.NET developer, but I hope the blow would work:

```
Dim number = Convert.ToInt32(Tnumber.Text)
Dim maxVal = Convert.ToInt32(Tmax.Text)

If number > maxVal Then 
    'do something
end if
```

In addition you need to keep the following in mind: If your text boxes are part of panels, group boxes or other containers, they will be part of the respective container's `Controls` collection, not of your form's `Controls` collection, so please use the debugger to find out whether you're actually finding the controls.

---

Edit after some comments to the question: Please note that looking up controls by name is **case sensitive**! So if the control is named `tbNumber9` and you're searching for `tbnumber9` you will not get a result.

---

Edit: To display the maximum number you'd do this:

```
Dim maxNumber = Int32.MinValue

For Count = 1 To 9
  Dim Tnumber = CType(Controls.Find("tbnumber" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
  Dim number = Convert.ToInt32(Tnumber.Text)

  If (number > maxNumber) Then
    maxNumber = number
    tbtest2.Text = maxNumber   

    If (maxNumber > 0) And (maxNumber < 30) Then
      tbTest1.Text = "0-30"
    elseif (maxNumber > 30) And (maxNumber < 50) Then
      tbTest1.Text = "30-50"
    end if
  End If
next
```

This stores the current maximum encoutered in `maxNumber` and if that value changed, updates the other text boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Thorsten. I'll give this a try right away.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I have no idea why, but It doesn't seem to work. I've been testing a little bit differently than my question to simplify the testing. Instead of using "MaxVal" i just put in a number manually. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: @MadsTheMan I commented the question.

Comment: @MadsTheMan I edited my answer to show you how to show the maximum. I'm not a VB.NET guy, but that should work. If it doesn't compile right away, you'll still understand what I mean, I hope :-)

Comment: Thorsten, YEEES! This worked perfectly. Finally! This have been bothering me for soooo many hours of trying and failing. Thanks for your great help (and patience), I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code only compares the numbers with the same index (so value 1 compared to value 1, value 5 compared to value 5).
Personally I would do the following, wich also makes it a bit more readable (imo)

```
'1-get-store all Integers
dim listof_tbnumber as new list (of Integer)
dim listof_tbmax as new list (of Integer)
For Count = 1 To 9
    listof_tbnumber.add(cint(Controls.Find("tbnumber" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault().Text))
    listof_tbmax.add(cint(Controls.Find("tbmax" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault().Text))
next

'2-compare
'If listof_tbnumber has at least 1 value greater then listof_tbmax
If (listof_tbnumber.FindAll(Function(x As Integer) x > listof_tbmax.Max)).Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox("isgreater")
End If
```

Comment: I'll give this a try as well. However, I notice an error `Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'Integer'` as I hover over the `(Controls.Find("tbmax" & Count, True).FirstOrDefault())` line. Any suggestions?